# Swift 2 to 3 Migration for prepareForSegue

Tags: swift, swift2, segue, swift3, ios10

This question might have been answered already but I could not find it.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
}
```

This code worked fine in swift 2 but now gives me an error to remove the override.

**Exact Error: "Method does not override any method from its superclass"**

**What is the new correct method for swift 3 for this? I can't seem to find any documentation on it anywhere.**

Comment: thanks was looking all over for the answer on here.

Comment: You also could have used this feature of Xcode: Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax...

Comment: That feature didn't work for some reason when I tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method signature is changed in swift 3.0

**Replace this**

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
```

**With**

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```